# Setting anacron on mac

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, cron, macintosh

I set cron to run script every day using **env EDITOR=nano crontab -e** where I wrote something like this **@daily path/to/sript.script**

Now I want to use anacron to be sure that script is going to be run when I log in if I was logged off at the time when it was scheduled. But I am not sure where to specify that.

I tried something like env EDITOR=nano anacron -e but that didn't work. Also, strange is that man anacron doesn't provide anything. I get this: "No manual entry for anacron"

Comment: FYI:  The last time I tried to use cron on OSX it was broken.

Comment: @mdpc well, cron works for me, but I can't find useful information about setting anacron. And I am total beginner, started learning Shell Scripting few days ago :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that `anacron` is not an installed utility in OS X. Scheduled tasks are handled by `launchd`, `cron` has been depreciated in OS X.